# Updating number fields to 3 decimal places Lotus Notes

Tags: field, lotus-notes, numeric, decimalformat

I have a view where there is a column displayed numeric values. Earlier the field which displayed this numeric value was of type text, but later I changed it to Number. As I want the column to display this numeric value with 3 decimal places, I updated the column properties to display 3 decimal places. Now the new documents show the column with 3 decimal places, but the older documents still do not show 3 decimal places.
Is there any function that I can use to make the number display 3 decimal places?

If the value is 1, then it must show 1.000, if 0.8 then 0.800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your column formula to

```
@ToNumber(YourField)
```

This way old values gets converted to a number and will be shown with 3 decimal places too.

Answer (score 0):

YOu could also either write an agent that changes the field type of that specific field in all document to number, or you could use a tool like NoteMan.Editor (from MartinScott) or scanEZ (from Ytria) to do the same. As a developer/admin, you should have at least one of those tools, preferably both.

I blogged about them a while back, if you want to learn more:

http://blog.texasswede.com/stuff-i-use-every-day-siued-noteman/

http://blog.texasswede.com/my-favorite-tools/

*I don't work for either of the companies, I am just a happy user of their tools.*